# Finding the Last Day of the Month in a Year (VB 6.0)

Tags: vb6

I'm creating a program that will predict the last day of the month. I've managed to give the months their value, but the year needs to be written as well in order to determine whether it's a leap year or not.
Objects:
2 Textboxes, 1 Command Button, 1 Label

> Needs to be Select case unfortunately.

My code:

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
Dim month, year As String

month = txtmonth.Text
year = txtyear.Text

Select Case month
Case "Feb", "February"
        lblday.Caption = CStr(Day(DateSerial(year, 3, 1) - 1))
Case "Jan", "January", "Mar", "March", "May", "Jul", "July", "Aug", "August", "Oct", "October", Dec, December
        lblday.Caption = "It has" & " " & CStr(Day(DateSerial(year, 3 + 2, 1) - 1)) & " " & "days"
'year/30/month
Case "April", "Jun", "June", "Sept", "September", "Nov", "November"
        lblday.Caption = "It has" & " " & CStr(Day(DateSerial(year, 3 + 1, 1) - 1)) & " " & "days"
'year/31/month
End Select

End Sub
```

Comment: `LastDayOfMonth = DateSerial(year, month + 1, 1) - 1`.
`NumOfDaysInMonth = Day(LastDayOfMonth)`.

Comment: You have June listed in both 30 and 31 day cases...

Comment: ...and no short codes `Jun`, `Jul`, `Oct`, `Apr`

Comment: Don't forget to put `Dec, December` in quotes too: `"Dec", "December"` and you are missing `"Apr"`. Also, maybe i am nitpicking, but I like everything to be nice and neat :) - you should change `"Sept"` to `"Sep"`, because you use a 3 character month short name everywhere else. That should give you an extra point for being neat on this assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the user supposed to enter into the textbox, string or a number?

If user input is a string, then you should put months in quotes like this `Case "Feb", "February"` and `month` needs to be declared as a `String` and assigned `txtmonth.Text` directly without `Val`

If user input is a number, then you need to remove all the short and long month names from the `Case` like `Feb` and `March` and use a number like this `Case 2 ' this is for February`

If you wish to optimize your code (assuming you absolutely have to have a `Case` in there), instead of asking user for a leap year you can calculate that yourself:

```
Case Feb, February
     lblday.Caption = Cstr(day(DateSerial(Year(Now), 3, 1) - 1))
```

if you didn't have to have a `Case` in there, all your code could of been optimized to this:

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
    lblday.Caption = CStr(Day(DateSerial(Year(Now), Month(DateValue(txtmonth.Text & " 0")) + 1, 1) - 1))
End Sub
```

With that code you can enter month number, month full name or month short name and it will work. It will assume the year to be the current year (you didn't specify whether user enters year or not).

**EDIT:**

I took your code and fixed the following:

- rearranged months because some months were in the case for 30-day month and they were 31-day months and the other way around
- changed case into lower case. This way you can enter month name in any case you wish. For example, before, only `Oct` would work. Now anything works: `oct`, `OCT`, `oCt`, `OcT` ...
- changed `Sept` to `sep` to be consistant
- changed the way you calculate days in a month. For 30 day months, you take the number of days from April with this `Day(DateSerial(year, 3 + 2, 1) - 1)` and for 31 day months from March with this `Day(DateSerial(year, 3 + 1, 1) - 1)` . What happens if in the future, we change the number of days in March? the whole logic collapses. I realize this is very unlikely, but still a possibility. There is absolutely no reason why we can't calculate each months on its own like this `CStr(Day(DateSerial(year, month(DateValue(txtmonth.Text & " 0")) + 1, 1) - 1))`
- because of the thing I changed above, I had to use function called `Month` but you already had a badly named variable called `month` so it was a conflict I had to fix and thus removed variable `month` altogether. If you have to have it, rename it to `myMonth` or something.

Some tips to have a well defined code:
- rename `year` to `myYear`
`use camel style: change all labels and text boxes to follow this naming convention. Example: rename`lblday`to`lblDay`and`txtmonth`to`txtMonth
 don't use variables if you don't need to. `month` variable was unnecessary. You could even remove `year` variable too, since you do not do any calculations on it at all.

```
    Private Sub Command1_Click()
        Dim year As String
        year = txtyear.Text

        Select Case LCase(txtmonth.Text)
            Case "feb", "february"
                lblday.Caption = CStr(Day(DateSerial(year, 3, 1) - 1))
            Case "april", "apr", "jun", "june", "sep", "september", "nov", "november"
                lblday.Caption = "It has" & " " & CStr(Day(DateSerial(year, month(DateValue(txtmonth.Text & " 0")) + 1, 1) - 1)) & " " & "days"
                'year/30/month
            Case "jan", "january", "mar", "march", "may", "jul", "july", "aug", "august", "oct", "october", "dec", "december"
                lblday.Caption = "It has" & " " & CStr(Day(DateSerial(year, month(DateValue(txtmonth.Text & " 0")) + 1, 1) - 1)) & " " & "days"
                'year/31/month
        End Select
    End Sub
```

Comment: I've written it in the description:
 "but the year needs to be written as well in order to determine whether it's a leap year or not." 

Btw, tried your first code, it works like a charm.. Thanks!
Also, we were obligated of using a Case, that's why I'm having a hard time determining the "month+year".

Will be editing my post now.

Answer (score 0):

```
LastDate= DateAdd("m", 1, DateAdd("d", -1 * Day(Date), Date))
```